# Need to convert an Array of Dicts (complex) into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my structure :

```
data = [{'dev_name': 'some_name',
'dev_connects': ['cn1', 'cn2', 'cn3', 'cn4'], 
'dev_type': 'some_type', 
'dev_features': ['ft 1', 'ft 2']},

{'dev_name': 'some_name2', 
'dev_connects': ['cn1', 'cn2', 'cn3', 'cn4'], 
'dev_type': 'some_type2', 
'dev_features': ['ft 1', 'ft 2']}]
```

So as you can see from my description , its an array of dicts.
I need to be able to create a dataframe that
will read each object and columnize every key, including what is inside the arrays data[i]['dev_connects'] and  data[i]['dev_features'] for every object :

| dev_name | connect1 | connect2 | connect3 | connect4 | dev_type | feature1 | feature2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some_name | cn1 | cn2 | cn3 | cn4 | some_type | ft1 | ft2 |
| some_name2 | cn1 | cn2 | cn3 | cn4 | some_type2 | ft1 | ft2 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a Pandas column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/split-a-pandas-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by breaking up your DataFrames into two separate (via `apply(pd.Series)` and then merging them back together. See the final code below.

```py
df_base = pd.DataFrame(data)[["dev_name", "dev_type"]]
df_connects = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("dev_name")["dev_connects"].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("connect")
df_features = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("dev_name")["dev_features"].apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("feature")

df_final = pd.merge(df_base, df_connects, on="dev_name").merge(df_features, on="dev_name")
```

This leaves you with the following final result.

|  | dev_name | dev_type | connect0 | connect1 | connect2 | connect3 | feature0 | feature1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | some_name | some_type | cn1 | cn2 | cn3 | cn4 | ft 1 | ft 2 |
| 1 | some_name2 | some_type2 | cn1 | cn2 | cn3 | cn4 | ft 1 | ft 2 |